# Automatically calculate cell using Swift

Tags: swift

Can anyone help me with trying to figure out how to structure my code so I can enter in a value into one cell and have other cells calculate based on that cells value.  For example, I want to have a static table view with 4 cells.  The first cell being a total amount and the other 3 cells will automatically calculate when a user enters data into the 3 remaining cells.  The data has to be dynamic.  For example, if the total cell is equal to 12.00 and a user enters 2 into one of the three cells, the numbers 5 and 5 get placed in the other two cells automatically.  I am think some kind of loop but can't figure out how to structure it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Writing a good question can be difficult for people new to the site, so please read [ask]. Questions about code need to include the code you have so far in order for people to understand the kind of situation you're dealing with.

Comment: Your code can be notified when a field changes. You could do any recalculations when ever there is a change to one of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UITableView with Prototype cells, not static, so you can reload it and have dynamic values in the text fields. If you want an example, let me know.